# How to export a rotating gif created by SliceDensityPlot3D/

Tags: gif-format

For example:
`SliceDensityPlot3D[(x^2 + y^2 + z^2) Exp[-10 Sqrt[ x^2 + y^2 +  z^2]], "CenterPlanes", {x, -.5, .5}, {y, -.5, .5}, {z, -.5, .5}]`

Comment: I see nothing rotating in the above. It is a single frame. How is rotation made? You should really show complete code to get better help. If you do not have rotation code, then how do you want it to rotate? around which axis? Your question needs more explanation and be more specific.

Answer (score 9):

Ok, while waiting for coeffee, here is an attempt. I am assuming you want to rotate this around z axis. But this can be easily changed by changing the `Rotate` command below. See help on `Rotate` to specify the rotation vector in 3D.

[image]

```
g = SliceDensityPlot3D[(x^2 + y^2 + 
      z^2) Exp[-10 Sqrt[x^2 + y^2 + z^2]], 
   "CenterPlanes", {x, -.5, .5}, {y, -.5, .5}, {z, -.5, .5}, 
   SphericalRegion -> True];
Manipulate[
 Graphics3D[Rotate[First@g, t Degree, {0, 0, 1}], Boxed -> False]
 ,
 {{t, 0, "degree?"}, 0, 360, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}
 ]
```

Now for making the animation gif file, this is one way. There are other ways, but I prefer this, as I found it gives better result.

```
SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]]
g = SliceDensityPlot3D[(x^2 + y^2 + 
      z^2) Exp[-10 Sqrt[x^2 + y^2 + z^2]], 
   "CenterPlanes", {x, -.5, .5}, {y, -.5, .5}, {z, -.5, .5}, 
   SphericalRegion -> True];
data = Table[Grid[{{Row[{ "angle = ", t, " degrees"}]},
     {Graphics3D[Rotate[First@g, t Degree, {0, 0, 1}], Boxed -> False]}
     }], {t, 0, 360, 1}
   ];
Export["anim.gif", data, "DisplayDurations" -> 0.06]
```

And now there is anim.gif file in your folder.  Here is a [link](https://12000.org/tmp/12242022/anim.gif) to the animation file. It is 5 MB.

[image]

The animation is very smooth.

Comment: The fact that you managed to answer before getting your coffee, should be awarded extra points in my opinion.

Answer (score 6):

- Since the multiple-variables function is fixed, I think you want to  rotate the slice to observer the value of function.
- for example, the plane `x==0` can be written as `{1,0,0}.{x,y,z}==0` where `{1,0,0}` is the normal vector. We rotate the normal vector `{1,0,0}` by `RotationMatrix` and get the new normal vector `RotationMatrix[θ, {0, 0, 1}] . {1, 0, 0}`.

```
Manipulate[
 SliceDensityPlot3D[(x^2 + y^2 + 
     z^2) Exp[-10 Sqrt[
      x^2 + y^2 + z^2]], {RotationMatrix[θ, {0, 0, 1}] . {1, 0,
       0} . {x, y, z} == 0, 
   RotationMatrix[θ, {0, 0, 1}] . {0, 1, 0} . {x, y, z} == 0, 
   RotationMatrix[θ, {0, 0, 1}] . {0, 0, 1} . {x, y, z} == 
    0}, {x, -.5, .5}, {y, -.5, .5}, {z, -.5, .5}, 
  PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"], {θ, 0, 2 π}]
```

- Test another function which is not spherical symmetric. To view the values of function, it is recommed to use `SliceContourPlot3D`.

```
Manipulate[
 SliceContourPlot3D[
  Sin[x] + y^2 - 
   z^3, {RotationMatrix[θ, {0, 0, 1}] . {1, 0, 0} . {x, y, z} ==
     0, RotationMatrix[θ, {0, 0, 1}] . {0, 1, 0} . {x, y, z} ==
     0, RotationMatrix[θ, {0, 0, 1}] . {0, 0, 1} . {x, y, z} ==
     0}, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, -1, 1}, 
  PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", 
  ColorFunction -> ColorData["ThermometerColors"], 
  Boxed -> False], {θ, 0, 2 π}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the SliceContourPlot3D; that is what I really want.

Comment: I save a docx file as a pdf to put on the Internet. When I do that the rotating gif file no longer rotates. It is no longer a gif file.

Comment: @LeonDavidRoper  https://12000.org/my_notes/Mathematica_animation_into_PDF_using_latex/index.htm